# I downloaded XCode 4.5.1 from MAc AppStore using my personal Apple Dev id but need to install it using my corporate Apple id

Tags: xcode, installation, xcode4.5, mac-app-store, iphone-developer-program

I develop on a Mac Pro (OSX 10.7.5) and my current version of XCode is 4.3 and I had installed this some months ago using my Corporate apple dev id.

I have just downloaded XCode 4.5.1 from the Mac AppStore and now realize that I downloaded this using my personal Apple Developer id. I need to now install this downloaded XCode 4.5.1 over the previous XCode version 4.3.

I tried kicking off the install using my Corp Dev id, and the installer complained that the package is associated with my other id (ie my personal app dev id) and that I should re-attempt the install under that (personal) id.  I could not find a way to clear the download so I finally kicked off the installer under my personal id.

I now have a long 2.5 hour wait until the install completes. I do not want a surprise at the end of that wait, so would appreciate if anyone can tell me if there are any implications or caveats installing this under my personal id?

(All my apps and devices etc in XCode are installed on devices under my corp apple id.) 
I just do not want this to complicate my workflow, or, if it will, I want to understand how, and also how to address the potential issues and caveats!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine... Just log in with your Cor ID when it asks you. I downloaded it from the Developer site. the .dmg file, and it works fine.